# how to fix this invalid syntax error

Tags: python, function, class, testing

I get an invalid syntax error for this code:

```
def __str__(self):
        s= 'Patron("'+self.name+'","'+self.patron_id+'","['+ \
        for book in self.borroweds:
            s+=str(book) + ', '
        if len(self.borroweds) != 0:
            s= s[:-2]
        s+='])' 
        return s



    for book in self.borroweds:
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

I know it's because I have a "\" but I put that so i can continue writing my code

Comment: What happens when you remove the `+ \`?  It looks like that would fix the problem to me...

Answer (score 2):

The backslash means the line is not over, so your code is exactly equivalent to

```
s = 'Patron("'+self.name+'","'+self.patron_id+'","['+ for book in self.borroweds:
```

which gives you a syntax error at the `for` keyword, since Python is looking for an expression that evaluates to a string there.  You should take out the `+` and the backslash.  It appears you would be happy to simply initialize `s` as follows:

```
s = 'Patron("'+self.name+'","'+self.patron_id+'","['
```

and then let subsequent line of your code add to the string `s`.

For details on the line structure of Python programs, including what is meant by explicit and implicit line joining, and how to think about the backslash character, see [this section of the Python reference manual](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
def __str__(self):
    books = ', '.join(self.borroweds)
    return 'Patron("{name}", "{id}", [{books}])'.format(name=self.name, id=self.patron_id, books=books)
```